# What's going on under the hood here? Javascript timer within a loop

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

Can someone break down what's going on here clearly?

```
function timerCheck() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Hello" + i);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

So as some of you may know, calling this function will not work as expected. What will end up happening is that this function will get called 5 times all at once with i set to 5 each time. This will be the output after 3 seconds:

```
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
```

I also understand that using the setInterval method is the right way to approach this kind of problem, but I am curious what's going on under the hood here. I really want to understand how Javascript works. Please note that I do not have a computer science background, just a self-taught coder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The previous question asks for a solution. I am looking for a thorough explanation of what's actually going on. So this is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you understand what's going on better:

```
function timerCheck() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        console.log("Hi" + i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Hello" + i);
        }, 3000);
        console.log("Bye" + i);
    }
}
```

You'll see

```
Hi0
Bye0
Hi1
Bye1
Hi2
Bye2
Hi3
Bye3
Hi4
Bye4
```

Immediately printed to the console, because all five iterations of the loop finish very quickly, and then after five seconds you'll see:

```
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
Hello5
```

because the timeouts (which were all set at approximately the same time) all occur at once, and since the loop already finished: `i == 5`.

This is caused by the scope of `i`. The variable `i` has a scope of everywhere after it is declared in `timerCheck();` There is no local i inside your anonymous function in setTimeout set there is no `var i`, and `i` isn't given as an argument to the function.

You can fix this easily with a closure, which will return a function that has a local copy of i:

```
function timerCheck() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        setTimeout((function(loc_i) {
            return function() {
                console.log("Hello" + loc_i);
            };
        })(i), 3000);
    }
}
```

Which will output:

```
Hello0
Hello1
Hello2
Hello3
Hello4
```

To understand this:

```
(function(loc_i) {
    return function() {
        console.log("Hello" + loc_i);
    };
})(i)
```

You have to know that a function can be executed immediately in Javascript. IE. `(function(x){ console.log(x); })('Hi');` prints `Hi` to the console. So the outer function above just takes in an argument (the current value of `i`) and stores it into a local variable to that function called `loc_i`. That function immediately returns a new function that prints `"Hello" + loc_i` to the console. That is the function that is passed into the timeout.

I hope that all made sense, let me know if you're still unclear on something.

Comment: Ok so let me see if I got this. The loop runs really fast and calls the setTimeout function 5 times around pretty much the same time (because the loop ran so fast). Therefore, while you wait for the setTimeout function to execute, the i already reaches 5. However, you can store the i locally each time by setting up a closure each time, but this will all still run at once right?

Comment: @Shaan Yeah, I think you got it. Try changing the `console.log` to: `console.log("Local: " + loc_i + ", i: " + i);`. In the second version and you'll see that both `loc_i` and `i` are defined in the inner function.

Comment: Yes I see it now. The loc_i points to the closure environment, and the i points to the i set in the function timer scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Variable scope in JavaScript is limited to functions.

In your example, the variable `i` is declared inside of `timerCheck`. This means that at the end of the loop, `i` will be equal to `5`.

Now, adding in the call to `setTimeout` doesn't change the fact that `i` is scoped to `timerCheck` and that `i` has been modified to equal `5` by the time the code inside each `setTimeout` call has run.

You can create a function that "captures" the value of `i` so that when you call it from inside your loop you get new variable scope for the `setTimeout` call:

```
function createTimer(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Hello" + j);
    }, 3000);
}

function timerCheck() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        createTimer(i);
    }
}
```

Since `createTimer` takes a parameter `j`, when you pass `i` from inside the for loop in `timerCheck` to `createTimer`, `j` is now scoped to `createTimer` so that each `setTimeout` call has its own `j`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an add-on to Andrews answer

If you try to set a variable that sets the output it explains the scope also.

```
function test()
{
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    t = "Hello " + i + "<br/>";
    document.write(t);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.write(t);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

as you can see the writes will be as expected but at the time the setTimeout fires the t variable will be the last set. Which will be Hello 4.

so the output will be

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
```

from the loop and

```
Hello 4
Hello 4
Hello 4
Hello 4
Hello 4
```

from the setTimeout