# display the dom process by jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display the process 'slowly' by adding a setTimeOut()

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){$("#result").prepend('dom<br/>')},2000);
}
```

Well, it doesn't work still, the dom process would display instantly after 2 second. What I want to do is 'see' the process of dom change, it would be like linux process file effect.

what should I do?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202182/looping-settimeout) May help you.

Comment: @FrayneKonok thanks for your link~ lnpyo gave a more clear answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend separating functions and use setInterval

OR use 'for ~' for initializing the timing like below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#result").prepend('dom<br/>');
    }, 2000 + 2000 * i);
}
```